# Set type of generic T return in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

For a given generic function

`func myGenericFunction<T>() -> T { }`

I can set what class that generic will be with

`let _:Bool = myGenericFunction()`

is there a way to do this so I don't have to define a variable separately on another line?

ex: `anotherFunction(myGenericFunction():Bool)`

Comment: You cannot "explicitly specialize a generic function". I was just doing some research on this. It was proposed on the mailing list, but doesn't seem to have gone anywhere: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160523/018960.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler needs some context to infer the type `T`. In a
variable assignment, this can be done with a type annotation or a cast:

```
let foo: Bool = myGenericFunction()
let bar = myGenericFunction() as Bool
```

If `anotherFunction` takes a `Bool` parameter then

```
anotherFunction(myGenericFunction())
```

just works, `T` is then inferred from the parameter type.

If `anotherFunction` takes a *generic* parameter then the
cast works again:

```
anotherFunction(myGenericFunction() as Bool)
```

---

A different approach would be to pass the type as an argument
instead:

```
func myGenericFunction<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T { ... }

let foo = myGenericFunction(Bool.self)
anotherFunction(myGenericFunction(Bool.self))
```